# Am I supposed to work on deliverables even if the work arrived after my contract ended?

Tags: contracts

I work as a contractual project-based specialist for a company for 1.5 years. My deliverables include a terminal report at the end of the project, although it wasn't explicitly stated in my contract. The problem with this is that my work is dependent on the output of my collaborators. So by the time my contract ended, I only got to finish 76% of the project because of this.

I already submitted my terminal report, but now my collaborators contacted me to say that they'll send me the remaining 24% of the project.

Am I still obligated to do the work?

Comment: This depends entirely on what it actually says in your contact. You'd have to check with a lawyer if you want to know about your legal obligations.

Comment: The only clause in the contract that can relate to my situation is this:
"That the Second Party shall perform work at a time and schedule to be agreed upon by both parties"

The attached paper for responsibilities just states that I need to submit a terminal report.

Comment: If you are project-based and not time-based, then you have to deliver the project right?

Comment: Who is voting to close this?  This is a good question!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what country is this?

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter This is more than curiosity- it is vital in a question about legal obligations. I'm guessing the close vote may have been because of this.

Comment: What does your contract indicate?  If the contract does not indicate the report is explicitly required, it sounds like, the report isn't required.

Answer (score 13):

IF they are asking you to work for free, then no, you don't have to do that.

IF they want the project done, they need to pay you and they need to sign a new contract.  If producing the report wasn't in your contract, than you are not obliged to complete it.  So long as you fulfilled your responsibilities, as outlined by the contract, you are fine.

Renegotiate with them and get your contract extended, and your pay increased too, while you are at it.

Comment: +100 Why would you  be obligated to work for free?

Answer (score 2):

I want to say no, but you might want to double check your contract and how it is worded. If the project is to completion, then they might have a legal standing. Otherwise if they paid you, then you are good to go. If they withheld payment and demand that you complete the project, then you might need to see a lawyer on how best to proceed especially if the contract has ended and mentioned nothing about unfinished work.

> The problem with this is that my work is dependent on the output of my collaborators. So by the time my contract ended, I only got to finish 76% of the project because of this.

If the contract specifically states that the collaborators complete work and hand it to you for completion, then yes, absolutely you have to complete it. Again it depends on the wording of the contract. If the contract mentions a start and end dates, then you're good to go. But if it only mentions a start date, then an installment of payments out to a date but states that work from collaborators must complete the work, then you may be held breach of contract.

Answer (score 2):

> but now my collaborators contacted me to say that they'll send me the
> remaining 24% of the project.
>
> Am I still obligated to do the work?

Since your initial contract is complete, you are not obligated to do any additional work.

Should you choose, you could sign a new contract calling for the completion of the project, but that is up to both you and them to come up with mutually agreeable terms or not.